# APK source code has no gradle files

Tags: android, gradle

New to android studio and Java development. I'm exploring some APK source code I found online and it does not have any gradle build files. I am using Android studio and wondering how to generate these files. The two options I am seeing seem to be (1) Create myself from scratch, (2) Export the project from Eclipse building these files in the export process. Any thoughts?

Repo here: https://github.com/jstoxrocky/weconnect

Comment: please link to code repo.

Comment: Added link to repo

Comment: Wait, did you make that repo? because that project layout is not that of either Eclipse or Android Studio. It looks like someone just dumped a bunch of libraries into a folder.

Comment: this link is not open..........

Answer (score 0):

If it is an eclipse project, I think there is an option in Android studio to import eclipse projects in the import wizard.

Comment: I am not sure if it is Eclipse. I tried this import process but it did not create and gradle files. I added a link to the repo in my question.

Comment: This project won't compile. If you want to run it you'll have to fix it from scratch and the resolve the dependencies yourself. This is just a collection of source files, not a running project.